# VS2015 Incremental Search Cursor Movement (aspx/ascx)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, user-controls, incremental-search

In Visual Studio 2010 when I did an incremental search (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) the cursor would automatically move to the first match (after the current cursor position) as I typed.

In Visual Studio 2015 all instances are highlighted as I type, but the cursor stays in the same place - I have to press <kbd>F3</kbd> to actually **go** to the first instance.  This is an annoying change.

Is there any way to get the cursor to move while typing in 2015?

There is no obvious option, either as part of the incremental search dialog or within `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Find and Replace`

---

It appears that this functionality **is** doing as I expect when editing `.cs`, `.vb`, `.html`, `.xml`, `.xslt` files... but it does **not** work (i.e. no cursor movement) when editing `.aspx` or `.ascx` files.

Again, I've looked for specific options around the `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor` area (especially the `HTML` and `HTML (Web Form)` sections), but can't find anything

---

Anybody finding this question because they're suffering the same situation, please go into the `Report a Problem` within Visual Studio 2015 (in `Send Feedback` in the top right corner of the IDE, to the left of the `Quick Launch`) and search/vote for...

> Incremental searching in aspx and ascx does not move cursor

(I've tried to find an external URL for the report, but can't find one.)